# Css with regex for id

Tags: css

I just want the first and third `id` to be red. How that possible?

**HTML & CSS:**

```css
#sections div[id^='s.*0'] {
    color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="sections">
    <div id="s10">one</div>
    <div id="s2">two</div>
    <div id="s30">three</div>
    <div id="t1">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no complex regex in CSS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use special CSS selector for that: `id$='0'` means id ends with 0 and `id^='s'` means id begins with s.

```css
#sections div[id$='0'][id^='s'] {
    color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="sections">
<div id="s10">one</div>
<div id="s2">two</div>
<div id="s30">three</div>
<div id="t1">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: amazing that it works, do you have a link to the w3c spec for this?

Comment: Thanks so much, it works. Would not have guessed i could join two regexes like that.

Comment: would be interesting to have this support matrix also for combination of two selectors https://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Comment: I was adding # before the div as I would do to an 'id' which didnt work. A small confusion initally, but it worked

Answer (score 2):

You could use the fact that those elements have an ID that begins with `s` using the begins with attribute selector (`[id^="s"]`) and ends with `0` using the ends with attribute selector (`[id$="0"]`):

```css
#sections div[id^="s"][id$="0"] {
    color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="sections">
<div id="s10">one</div>
<div id="s2">two</div>
<div id="s30">three</div>
<div id="t1">four</div>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, similar to Pawel's above.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the ID was design to do, CSS does not support Regex. However, your solution is to use classes.

```
#sections .s-class {
    color: red;  
}
<div id="sections">
    <div id="s10" class='s-class'>one</div>
    <div id="s2" class='s-class'>two</div>
    <div id="s30" class='s-class'>three</div>
    <div id="t1">four</div>
</div>
```

Only those with that specific class will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a pseudo selector:

```
#sections:nth-child(1), #sections:nth-child(3) {
  color:red;
}
```

It's not supported in IE8 or lower, but should be fine elsewhere.