# CSS, how to target id tag in html that changes on page refresh

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the background color of section of the html (built on Wordpress, using Flatsome theme) that has a section's id that changes every time that page is refreshed; dynamic id in a sense.

For example the website has:

```
<div class="row row-large row-solid" style="max-width:1200px" id="row-1887573675">
```

but when I refresh the page, the id changes to something else. So, if I want to change the background colour with the following:

```
    .page-id-2001 #row-1887573675 {background-color:rgb(196, 213, 242);}
```

It will not work, I guess the id changes and would be able to target the id tag.

I'm wondering if there is a way to target this div section so I can change the background colour.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem to add second `id` or add some `class` or if you can not change this element you can wrap it to your own `div` and add styles for it?

Comment: If you want only dynamic search and you always know the structure of generated `id` then you can use [CSS regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497352/css-with-regex-for-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `CSS [attribute^=value] Selector`, i hope it'll resolve your issue. Thank You

**Documentation:** https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

```
.page-id-2001 [id^='row-'] {background-color:rgb(196, 213, 242);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a special class to your element and then select that specific class in your stylesheet and give it the rule you wish (in this case: `background-color:rgb(196, 213, 242);`).

If it doesn't work, it means there is a conflict of specificity between CSS declarations. That may be the reason you wanted to use an ID, but if using an ID doesn't work well, I suggest you should give a higher specificity score to your declaration by other means.

You can find a table that shows you how to give a declaration a higher score. [Cascade and inheritance MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#understanding_the_cascade)